# Close Windows Form while it is initializing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms app that checks user credentials as it starts.
If autharization fails I want to close the app.
So I have been using the following

```
Public Sub New()
_CurrentUser.GetuserDetails
If _CurrentUser.IsAuthorized then
    'Let the app start
Else
   'Shut it down
    Me.Close()
End IF

End Sub
```

However this produces a 
"Cannot access a disposed object"
 error
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `Me.Close()`, call `Application.Exit()`

Comment: Environment.Exit(exitCode) will work from inside Sub New(), for anyone else that gets here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick reply Jay
Using Application.Exit certainly stopped the error occuring.
Unfortunatly it didnt close the app either.:)

It did let me see that the next executed section was the Form_Load event
so I moved all my authorization code to there and then
Application.Exit worked a treat.
Me.Close also worked fine in the Load block.
Thanks again